# Intersection of curves on surfaces and the sheaf $\mathcal O_{C\cap C'}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, schemes, intersection-theory

Let $S$ be a (complex) projective surface and let $C,C'\subset S$ two closed irreducible curves (namely two prime Weil divisors). It is well defined the scheme $C\cap C'$ (as fibered product of $C\rightarrow S$ and $C'\rightarrow S$) which is a closed subscheme of $X$ but I have some problems to understand the sheaf indicated as  $\mathcal O_{C\cap C'}$.

1) Some books say that  $\mathcal O_{C\cap C'}$ is the "skyscraper sheaf" supported by the set theoretic intersection $|C|\cap |C'|$. But what is this sheaf? Can you define it please? (For example what are its global sections?)

2) Why if $x\in C\cap C'$, then the local ring $\left(\mathcal O_{C\cap C'}\right)_x$ is equal to $\frac{\mathcal O_{X,x}}{(f,g)}$ where $f,g$ are local equations for $C$ and $C'$.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried thinking locally your situation? Namely, you know that fiber product respects pullbacks, and so on an affine of $S$, say $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ where $C=V(f)$ and $C'=V(g)$ what is the fiber product over $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$? What is $A/(f)\otimes_A A/(g)$?

Comment: Do you know how to get from an effective Weil divisor to a closed subscheme? Do you know how to intersect subschemes?

Comment: Yes and yes :) !!

Comment: thank you for the bounty! I hope you are happy with the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, a note about terminology. If $\iota: Y \hookrightarrow X$ is a closed subscheme and $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-modules on $Y$, it makes no difference whether we compute $H^i(Y, \mathcal{F})$ or $H^i(X, \iota_* \mathcal{F})$. This "trick" is used so often that it pays to be a little sloppy with the notation and not write $\iota_*$. Sometimes we say "view it as a sheaf on the bigger space" to mean the same thing: take $\iota_*$ of the sheaf.

That is what is happening in your notation: $\mathcal O_{C \cap C'}$ is just the structure sheaf of $C \cap C'$, viewed as a sheaf on $X$. To be precise, one would write it with an $\iota_*$. Since $C \cap C'$ is a bunch of points, this is also sometimes called a skyscraper sheaf. So if $V$ is an open subset of $S$, we have
$$\iota_*\mathcal O_{C \cap C'}(V) = \mathcal O_{C \cap C'}(V \cap C \cap C')  ``="  \{\text{ functions on } C \cap C' \cap V\}.$$

EDIT: I missed your second question. This is the definition of closed immersion: functions on the closed subscheme all arise as restrictions of functions on the ambient scheme. For any affine $U$ containing $x$, there is a surjective "restriction map" $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{O}_{C \cap C'}(U)$, and to say that $f$ and $g$ are local equations for $C$, $C'$ is to say that (for a judicious choice of $U$) $f$ and $g$ generate the kernel of this map (more precisely, $f$ generates the kernel of $\mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{O}_C(U)$, similarly for $g$, and then use the definition of the fiber product. Note that in this parenthetical remark I am using the "abuse of language" I referred to in the first paragraph of this answer).

Comment: in general a local equation of a divisor is what follows: $C$ induces a prime divisor $C_x$ in $\text{Spec}(\mathcal O_{X,x})$. It turns out that $C_x$ is principal, so $C_x=(f)$ for some $f\in\mathcal O_{X,x}$. Now $f$ is local equation of $C$. 

I don't understand why I can recover $f$ in the kernel of  $i^\#:\mathcal O_X\rightarrow i_{\ast} \mathcal O_C$.

Comment: To show the kernel is generated by $f$: on the one hand, clearly $f$ is in the kernel (to say $C_x = (f)$ is to say $f$ vanishes on $C$). On the other, if $g$ is in the kernel, then consider the divisor of $g/f$ (thought of as a global meromorphic function) to conclude that $f|g$ (in any neighborhood of $C$ where $f$ is holomorphic).